# Mach-O Linking Error Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am developing an app with Xcode in Swift. In order to offer both a free and paid version, I decided to make one project, then clone it and add iAds to create a free version.

I duplicated the file containing the XCode project, and edited the name under "Identity and Type" to be the new name I want.

However, when I try to compile the app, I get the error

Apple Mach-O Linker Error

```
ld: file not found: /Users/myuserfolder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CryptoCalc_Lite-acbredfhamttzgbmzrevebruhaha/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CryptoCalc.app/CryptoCalc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I put the name back to what it originally way, it compiles just fine.

Comment: This is not a good way to do this.  This is what targets are for.  You should try using that, then you will avoid this problem all together.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it - if you'll give instructions on how to do it your way as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @borrrden thanks! If you post how to do this w targets as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.